# Adjusting WPF control size in order to fit to window size

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How can I check how many lines of the ListView fit in the window (Main Window).
I assume that the window is maximized, and only the system settings determine the size of the window. 
ListView is docked in DockPanel with the option FillLastChild.

Does WPF provide mechanisms to automate such a operation?

Regards.

Here is my WPF. I'd like to know how many items fit in "lstBox" in order to control paging using Back and Next buttons.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel x:Name="MainPanel" LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnNext" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,0,0" Width="40" />
        <Button x:Name="btnBack" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Height="23" Content="Back" Margin="0,6,0,0" />
    </Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ListBoxTemplate}" BorderBrush="#FF000000" 
                  BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically adjust the height and or width of the control? Have you put it inside a grid and adjusted the height to auto?

Comment: Show us your XAML. Build an example that demonstrates your problem with as few lines as possible.

Comment: XAML can be viewed above

Answer (score 0):

Arrange everything in the main Grid. In the Grid row or column definitions:

"Auto" makes the Grid cell adjust to the size of the control present in it
"*" is used to handle available free space(left after the creation of other columns or rows).

For a detailed tutorial: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-units/

You will surely be able to adjust your controls as you desire after reading it

You do not need this listbox template just for paging. WPF offers built-in UI Virtualization. If you need Data Virtualization(paging), you should refer to this:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization